# How to pass a smooth line through points positioned on a bullet-shaped curve?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data frame is

```
result_df <- structure(list(rp = c(0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 
0.08, 0.09, 0.1, 0.11, 0.12, 0.13, 0.14, 0.15, 0.16, 0.17, 0.18, 
0.19, 0.2), MV = c(0.3396, 0.3076, 0.2788, 0.2532, 0.2308, 0.2116, 
0.1956, 0.1828, 0.1732, 0.1668, 0.1636, 0.1636, 0.1668, 0.1732, 
0.1828, 0.1956, 0.2116, 0.2308, 0.2532, 0.2788)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

When plotted it looks like a bullet shaped curve. How can I pass a smooth curve through these points? I tried the following, but did not work.

```
  ggplot(result_df, aes(x = (MV)^0.5, y = rp)) +
    geom_point() +
    labs(title = "Smooth Line Plot of rp against MV", x = "s.d.", y = "rp")+
    theme_bw()+
    stat_smooth(aes(x = (MV)^0.5, y = rp), method = "lm",
                formula = y ~ poly(x, 12), se = FALSE)
```

Comment: No idea how to do it in R but the plot obviously has a quadratic dependence on rp. Almost any polynomial fitter should get a model something like  y = 16x^2-3.68x+0.375 (where y is MV and x is rp). Fit looks suspiciously exact so probably not real data. Excel or gnuplot are handy for a quick look see at data that you want to examine graphically.

Answer (score 3):

`stat_smooth` will only give you a single estimate for each point on the x axis, whereas to draw a smooth curve through the upper and lower limbs of your bullet would require two values at each point on the x axis. The easiest way to get round this is to swap the x and y axes, then flip the co-ordinates of the final plot:

```r
ggplot(result_df, aes(rp, MV^0.5)) + 
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ poly(x, 12), se = FALSE) +
  geom_point() +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(title = "Smooth Line Plot of rp against MV", y = "s.d.", x = "rp")
```

[image]

Comment: just discovered that `stat_smooth` can also take an `orientation = "y"` argument which does the flipping inside the layer for same results.

Comment: I did _not_ know that @AndyBaxter. That's very handy. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

## plot rp against MV

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

result_df %>%
`dplyr`::arrange(rp)%>%
`ggplot`(aes(x = (MV)^0.5, y = rp)) +
`geom_point`() +
labs(title = "Smooth Line Plot of rp against MV", x = "s.d.", y = "rp")+
theme_bw()+
geom_path()